# Problem with executing an SQL insert statement in access using VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, insert, insert-into

I'm trying this SQL statement but I keep getting an error

```
Run-time error '3061':
Too few parameters. Expected 4.
```

The statement I am trying to execute is:

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO MasterTable (AdmissionNumber, Surname, Forename, TutorGroup) VALUES (intAdmissionNo, strSurName, strForeName, strTutorGroup)"
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

The 4 values intAdmissionNo, strSurName, strForeName and strTutorGroup all have values and the fields all exist.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Where have you provided the actual values that you want to insert???

Comment: They're previously declared, they show up in the watch window as well.  (but admission no will be a number that changes, the forname/surname are forname/surname and tutorgroup changes also).  One example might be: ...VALUES (5040, Smith, John, 10R)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done that from VBA, but unless I'm mistaken you're not sending in the variables as you think you are. Try this line instead of your current one:

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO MasterTable (AdmissionNumber, Surname, Forename, TutorGroup) VALUES (" & intAdmissionNo & ", " & strSurName & ", " & strForeName & ", " & strTutorGroup & ")"
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, but that now gives me a run time error 3075. Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression '10R'.  (10R is what TutorGroup has evaluated it)

Comment: tutorgroup is alphabetic, not numeric, add quotes ", '" & strTutorGroup & "')"

Comment: Ahh, thanks :) I put quotes around all the strings and it worked.  Although now I seem to get an error every time someone's name has an apostrophe in it.  Any ideas how to get round this without removing the apostrophes?

Comment: @Tim: Replace any instance of an apostrophe with two apostrophe's. Something like this `Surname = Replace(Surname, "'", "''")` I think.